# MSSQL nvarchar(max) on opensuse-webserver

Tags: php, sql-server, image, unixodbc, nvarchar

I am currently creating a webform on an opensuse-webserver that includes a `textarea` in which it you can add pictures by using copy and paste. We did this by using a `DIV` and giving it the `"contenteditable="True"` value.

This results in a very long string in the POST, easily going above 120000 characters.

I have to use a MSSQL Database in which I wanted to save everything.

Saving and selecting this String within Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio using `nvarchar(max)` is not an issue. But when trying to select this over the Webserver the driver tries to allocate over 4GB of memory (This is a known issue, see [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=69975)) and thus gives a Fatal Error:

> Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967293 bytes).

I have also tried using the `BINARY` or `IMAGE` data type but have not been able to read the data back from the Database using PHP.

Sadly I have not been able to come up with a solution regarding this, so I hope that someone here will be able to help me.

Comment: Cleaned and documented code; reorganized question

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'); at the start of your script and try.

One more thing I can suggest is, create an image from the string and store it in your server, then only store the path to that image in your DB.
try to use the function imagecreatefromstring(

Comment: This sadly does not work. I am working on a webserver from the company and this only makes it that the page simply cannot be displayed.